# ReactJS npm test : SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier "Import"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to use **rasa-webchat** Widget in an new ReactJs project but
when I do npm test in bitbucket pipeline I  get the following error

/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/rasa-webchat/index.js:1
    ({"Object.":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import React from 'react';

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
  1 | import React, { Component } from 'react';
> 2 | import { Widget } from 'rasa-webchat';
```

I tried the same code changing the import from **rasa-webchat** to **react-chat-widget** and it works fine. So I think there is something *wrong* happening due to this plugin

I'm using this Docker image on my pipeline: **node:11.6.0**

Here are my dependencies :

```
  "dependencies": {
    "rasa-webchat": "github:mrbot-ai/rasa-webchat",
    "react": "^15.6.2",
    "react-chat-widget": "^2.1.4-1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.2",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.3"
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough points to comment, but did you try the Usage with Docker section on the rasa-webchat readme?

https://github.com/mrbot-ai/rasa-webchat#usage-with-docker

Comment: Thanks for the hint ! But I still face an issue.
Test suite failed to run
    Jest encountered an unexpected token [...]
    Here's what you can do:
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

Not sure what this means

Comment: If I disable tests I got this error during npm run build

./node_modules/rasa-webchat/index.js
SyntaxError: /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/rasa-webchat/index.js: Unexpected token (9:6)
ReactDOM.render(
<Widget

Comment: @Woody sound like webpack setting problem for me

Comment: What do you mean ?